# ArangoDb - custom property name

Tags: json, properties, key, arangodb

Is there a way to get the value from key "· gc.alloc.rate"? Because the standard reference name after the dot returns an error.

```
...
  "secondaryMetrics": {
    "·gc.alloc.rate": {
      "score": 502.22945873992126,
      "scoreError": "NaN",
      "scoreConfidence": [
        "NaN",
        "NaN"
      ],
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either escape the attribute name with backticks or forward ticks, or use the bracket notation and a quoted string:

```
secondaryMetrics.`·gc.alloc.rate`
secondaryMetrics.´·gc.alloc.rate´
secondaryMetrics['·gc.alloc.rate']
secondaryMetrics["·gc.alloc.rate"]
```

https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/fundamentals-syntax.html#names